# The image inside the columns doesnt fit in the 320px screen

Tags: html, css

How to wrap images responsively inside the columns. The images doesn't fit inside the column and the screen of 360px.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cormorant+Garamond|EB+Garamond|Great+Vibes" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4"><img src="https://www.google.com.ph/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=imgres&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Fcss%2Focean.jpg&psig=AOvVaw3Li5y49HHEkCc_jj8yhZQn&ust=1509070722216853"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4"><img src="https://www.google.com.ph/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=imgres&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Fcss%2Focean.jpg&psig=AOvVaw3Li5y49HHEkCc_jj8yhZQn&ust=1509070722216853"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4"><img src="https://www.google.com.ph/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=imgres&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Fcss%2Focean.jpg&psig=AOvVaw3Li5y49HHEkCc_jj8yhZQn&ust=1509070722216853"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4"><img src="https://www.google.com.ph/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=imgres&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Fcss%2Focean.jpg&psig=AOvVaw3Li5y49HHEkCc_jj8yhZQn&ust=1509070722216853"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4"><img src="https://www.google.com.ph/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=imgres&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Fcss%2Focean.jpg&psig=AOvVaw3Li5y49HHEkCc_jj8yhZQn&ust=1509070722216853"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4"><img src="https://www.google.com.ph/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=imgres&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Fcss%2Focean.jpg&psig=AOvVaw3Li5y49HHEkCc_jj8yhZQn&ust=1509070722216853"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the `max-width` attribute on the images and they should fit nicely.

css: `img{max-width:100%}`

Or, you can apply the style directly to the element. For example, change this:

```
<img src="https://www.google.com.ph/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=imgres&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Fcss%2Focean.jpg&psig=AOvVaw3Li5y49HHEkCc_jj8yhZQn&ust=1509070722216853">
```

to this:

```
<img style="max-width:100%" src="https://www.google.com.ph/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=imgres&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Fcss%2Focean.jpg&psig=AOvVaw3Li5y49HHEkCc_jj8yhZQn&ust=1509070722216853">
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare width and height like this.

```
<img style="width:100%; height:auto;" src="https://www.google.com.ph/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=imgres&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Fcss%2Focean.jpg&psig=AOvVaw3Li5y49HHEkCc_jj8yhZQn&ust=1509070722216853">
```

Answer (score 0):

add this style and your images should automatically fit which ever grid size you set, Avoid pixel in Grid unless you need a fix size try percentage like 20%, rest depends on your project

```
<style>    
body img{max-width:100%;width:100%;vertical-align:unset;text-align:center;}
</style>
```

That's it.